# Python copy a file from appdata

Tags: copy, appdata

how do I copy a file that is present in c:/users/robert/appdata/OpenOffice/work.txt from here to the folder where i execute the python script ? and without adding the folder name (robert) in python script?

```css
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import getpass,shutil,os
src="C:\Users\%s\AppData\OpenOffice\work.txt" %(getpass.getuser())

dest=os.getcwd()
def copyFile(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copy(src, dest)
        print("Done")
    # eg. src and dest are the same file
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Error: %s' % e)
    # eg. source or destination doesn't exist
    except IOError as e:
        print('Error: %s' % e.strerror)

copyFile(src,dest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer